# Gradle EBean Enhancement - Entity not enhanced

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, persistence, ebean

I've been Googling for hours, maybe I don't understand enough about it to truly describe it, maybe my Googling talents have declined over the past day.

I've upgrade to EbeanORM 3.2.5 from 2.8.1 finally realizing they kept up but just changed the artifact name.  That being said, I'm getting the enhancement error.

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Entity type class com.bloomhealthco.fixtures.entities.ProductFamilyProductGroupRelationEntity is not an enhanced entity bean. Subclassing is not longer supported in Ebean

I'm working with Gradle, so the Maven fix doesn't suit me.  I found the avaje-agentloader and tried to implement that:

```
buildscript{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.avaje:avaje-agentloader:1.1.1"
    }
}

import org.avaje.agentloader.AgentLoader

task fixturesTests(type: Test) {
    description "Executes all fixtures tests."
    AgentLoader.loadAgentFromClasspath("avaje-ebeanorm-agent","debug=1");

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

I have also tried putting it in my test setup.  Currently I'm just testing the entities work as expected.

```
import org.avaje.agentloader.AgentLoader

class EntitySpec extends Specification {

    setupSpec() {
        AgentLoader.loadAgentFromClasspath("avaje-ebeanorm-agent","debug=1");
    }

    .........
    .........
    .........
}
```

Am I not creating the reference to the agentloader correctly or am I not even on the right page?

I also don't really understand what enhancement is.

Comment: Any update since April? I have the same question.

Comment: I have not.  I just used an old version of eBean that doesn't need enhanced entities.

Comment: Gradle plugin doesn't enhance until before running tests.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing a dependency or two. My dependency block looks as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm:4.1.4'
    compile 'org.avaje:avaje-agentloader:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent:4.1.5'
}
```

It looks like you have the agentloader library, but I don't see the agent library. You might try adding that and seeing if the exception goes away.